# Castle Windsor PerWebRequest Lifestyle is not being honored

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I'm working on a 3-tier MVC application. The data layer contains an EF4 code-first DbContext:

```
public class MyDataContext : DbContext
{
    // DbSet<>s...
}
```

There's also an interface and an implementation for DI:

```
public interface IContextFactory
{
    MyDataContext GetContext();
}

public class ContextFactory : IContextFactory
{
    readonly MyDataContext context;
    public ContextFactory(MyDataContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public MyDataContext GetContext()
    {
        return this.context;
    }
}
```

And a repository pattern:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T Create();
    void Insert(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    ...
    void Save();
}

public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
  where TEntity: class, new()
{
    public Repository(IContextFactory factory)
    {
        this.context = factory.GetContext();
        this.set = factory.Set<TEntity>();
    }
    ...
}
```

The upper tiers access the entities by having `IRepository<>` injected with castle windsor. Custom providers/modules explicitly `.Resolve<>()` them as needed.

The data layer is being registered in a castle `IWindsorInstaller`:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<MyDataContext>()
    .DependsOn(new Hashtable() { {"connectionStringName", "DefaultConnection"} })
    .LifestylePerWebRequest());

container.Register(
    Component.For<IContextFactory>()
    .ImplementedBy<ContextFactory>()
    .LifestylePerWebRequest());

container.Register(
     Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>))
    .ImplementedBy(typeof(Repository<>))
    .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

I wouldn't know anything was wrong - my tests don't cover the data context - but in debug mode my data context's constructor is getting called nearly a dozen times per web request.

**edit**: Whilst it does not explain why `Repository` and `MyDataContext` aren't getting scoped to web requests, my break point inside the constructor reveals an identical call stack all dozen-or-so times that its constructed: `MembershipProvider.GetUser -> new Repository(IContextFactory)`. I have no explicit calls to `GetUser` - what in the world would cause FormsAuthentication to call GetUser so many times?

Answer (score 2):

Add something like this in your Global.asax.cs file:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(this.Request.RequestType + " " + this.Request.RawUrl);
    }
```

Hook up with debugger and verify that there realy is just one request per "request". Maybe you have ajax requests running parallelly. Or mayby you have your content elements (js files, images) protected and their gets are executing C# code.

Comment: A fair idea. Refreshing the page I've been working on this evening traced four lines to the output window: `GET /`, `GET /favicon.ico`, `GET /control-panel/index`, `GET /favicon.ico`. Still remains a mystery why the database is getting hit so many times (I'm pretty sure membership is done lazily and formsauthentication data is packed in to the auth cookie). Even when I figure that out, I've got the problem of each `IOC.Resolve<IRepository<EntityType>>` creating a new data connection.