# Castle Windsor 3 persists PerWebRequest objects across multiple web requests

Tags: asp.net, castle-windsor, perwebrequest

I have an MVC 4 project and am trying to inject a PerWebRequest object into my controller. However it appears the object is not being recreated across multiple requests

```
 private static IWindsorContainer InitializeWindsor()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This());

        // Add Factory facility
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

        // Register all controllers from this assembly
        foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            container.Register(
                AllTypes.FromAssembly(assembly).BasedOn<Controller>().Configure(c => c.LifestyleTransient())
                );
        }

        // Register HTTP Handlers
        container.Register(Component.For<HttpRequestBase>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest.UsingFactoryMethod(() => new HttpRequestWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request)));
        container.Register(Component.For<HttpContextBase>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest.UsingFactoryMethod(() => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)));


        // Register components
        container.Register(Component.For<PerWebRequestObject>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
}
```

Here's my PerWebRequestObject:

```
public class PerWebRequestObject
{
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public PerWebRequestObject()
    {
        DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Debug.WriteLine("Created: " + DateCreated.ToLongTimeString());
    }
}
```

Here's my TestController:

```
public class TestController : BaseController
{
    public PerWebRequestObject pwrObject { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(pwrObject.DateCreated.ToLongTimeString());
        return new ContentResult();
    }
}
```

Why is this not working? Note that I'm using the WindsorControllerFactory and releasing the Controller like so:

```
    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        var disposableController = controller as IDisposable;
        if (disposableController != null)
            disposableController.Dispose();

        _windsorContainer.Release(controller);
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643594/castle-windsor-perwebrequest-lifestyle-is-not-being-honored

Comment: Thanks - just tried this and it is definitely spawning a new request every time, and creates a new controller... Not sure why my PerWebRequestObject is acting like a singleton. Could it possibly be related to me using the MVC4 beta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to Castle Windsor v3.1 fixed the issue for us without needing to change any code.

I assume there must've been an issue with the combination of Windsor v3.0 + MVC 4.

Answer (score 5):

Two things:

- how do you know the object is not lifecycled properly (not re-created across web-requests)?

One possible explanation is that your dependency looks like this:

controller --> a singleton --> your per-web-request-component

this is a lifestyle mismatch, and that would explain the behaviour you're seing

- do not dispose the controller. That's container's job.